# is there any identities on cotangent on a triangle inside two parallel lines?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I came across some engineering paper and equation in the paper doesn't seem to make sense unless cot(A)=cot(-B) in the image below.

But I never heard of such identity before.

Can cot(A)=cot(-B) be true or it can't be true in general?

[image]

Comment: Just from the figure, we can vary $\angle A$ for fixed $\angle B$. Hence for fixed $\cot(-\angle B)$, we can have arbitrary values of $\cot(\angle A)$. Hence what you are claiming is not true in general, unless some other conditions are present.

Answer (score 0):

$\cot A=-\cot B$ if $A+B=180°$

This is impossible because of the basic external theorem in triangles which asserts that external angle $(180°-B)$ is *strictly* larger than internal angles $A$ and the third on the top.

Send other detail on your equation. Maybe the problem is elsewhere

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No, it's only true in that diagram if B = 180° - A, and then you have two parallel lines, not a triangle.